# android sqlite: Insert query syntax error

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

Hi I am trying to insert values in my sqlite database but i get "unrecognized token" for the last value exception for byte array. here is code:

```
 public void insertImage(String userName, String userMob, String meterReading, String readingAddress, String readingRemark, String readingDate , byte[] imageBytes) {
        try {
            mDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + IMAGES_TABLE +"(" + USER_NAME + ", " + USER_MOB + ", " + METER_READING_TEXT + ", " + READING_REMARKS + ", " + READING_DATE + ", " + IMAGE + ")" +
                    " VALUES (" + userName + ", " + userMob + ", " + meterReading + ", " + readingAddress + ", " + readingRemark + ", " + readingDate + ", " + imageBytes + ");");
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("-----","dasdasdas");
        }
        }
```

Comment: Use parameterized queries.  That way,  you won't have problems like this.

Comment: learn this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324641/cant-insert-byte-into-mysql-using-java

Comment: Strings must be **quoted** in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

seems you have  6 entry in into clause  but 7 in values

```
try {
        mDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + IMAGES_TABLE + 
          "(" + USER_NAME + ", " +
           USER_MOB + ", " + 
           METER_READING_TEXT + ", " + 
           READING_REMARKS + ", " + 
           READING_DATE + ", " + 
           IMAGE + ")" +
          " VALUES (" + userName + ", " +
           userMob + ", " + 
           meterReading + ", " + 
           readingAddress + ", " + 
           readingRemark + ", " + 
           readingDate + ", " + 
           imageBytes + ");");
    }
```

the number of element in both clause must match

Comment: why downvote ...  could this is not the only error but is a valid suggestio for code provided  by op